# Using fscanf to input data into a dynamic struct pointer array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays, scanf

I have an assignment and have run into somewhat of a snag. The following code is supposed to take input from a file, read it into a struct that I have defined, and do so without any limit to the number of input lines. However, it segfaults at line *24*:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <stdlib.h>
3 #include <string.h>
4
5 typedef struct __student {
6         int ID;
7         char fname[33];
8         char lname[33];
9         float grade;
10 } student;
11
12 void partA(FILE *fp) {
13
14         int i, r;
15         i = r = 0;
16         int N = 1000;
17         student **S;
18
19         S = (student **)malloc(sizeof(student *) * N);
20
21
22         while(!feof(fp)){
23                 fscanf(fp, "%d %[^,], %s %f", &S[i]->ID, S[i]->lname, S[i]->fname, &S[i]->grade ); // segfault occurs on this line
24                 printf("%d %s %s %f\n", S[i]->ID, S[i]->fname, S[i]->lname, S[i]->grade);
25                 i++;
26                 printf("Something's happening, at least");
27                 if(i == N){
28                         N *= 2;
29                         S = (student **)realloc(S, sizeof(student) * N);
30                         if(S == NULL) {
31                                 printf("Memory reallocation failed; Fatal error.");
32                                 break;
33                         }
34                 }
35         }
36 }
```

I tested the code before, although at that point I was using static arrays and wanted to change to a dynamic size. However, even gdb with offers very little help besides the line number. Do I need to individually malloc each **student** struct, or am I missing something entirely different here?

**EDIT**: It seems the code works when I allocate memory to each *student* in the while loop through:

```
S[i] = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student));
```

So that seems to have fixed the issue. I'll run some tests to make sure.

Comment: This looks like an odd link-list \ 2D array. Which do you want?

Comment: Could you explain the format of the input lines?
`"%d %[^,], %s %f"` Why are you doing that with the `','`?

Comment: andre, that was an oversight, I apologize. I tried a LL approach earlier but found it was not what I needed.

@AdriánLópez The input data is in the format <int> <string>, <string> <float>. I am merely using a scanset to get rid of the comma. My apologies for not mentioning that!

Comment: Yes, you either have to allocate memory for each student, or you could allocate an array of `students` to begin with, rather than an array of pointers to students. I.e. replace `S = (student**)malloc(sizeof(student*)*N)` by `S = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student)*N)`.

Comment: Indeed the problem was with your memory allocation. You need memory for `N * the size of the structure`, not `N * the size of a pointer to your structure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 19 you are allocating enough space for N student pointers but not allocating space for the student structs them selves. You would need to do something like:

```
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     S[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct __student));
}
```

Comment: Oh oops looks like you answered your own question with the edit.

Comment: I did, but I'll accept the answer either way since it is the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Besides your malloc problem, you have major issues with the two lines

```
while(!feof(fp)){
    fscanf(fp, "%d %[^,], %s %f", &S[i]->ID, S[i]->lname, S[i]->fname, &S[i]->grade ); // segfault occurs on this line
```

One problem is that your `lname` and `fname` fields are fixed size 33 char arrays, which means that if your input has more than 32 characters at that point, you'll run off the end of the array and corrupt things.  Another problem is that you don't check the return value of `fscanf` to see if something went wrong (such as an EOF), leading you to try to print a garbage record when you get to the end of the file.  What you want instead is something like:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d %32[^,],%32s%f", &S[i]->ID, S[i]->lname, S[i]->fname, &S[i]->grade) == 4) {
```

for your loop control.

**edit**

The problem with `while(!feof(fp))` (and why its almost always an error) is that `feof(fp)` only returns true AFTER you've tried to read PAST the end of the file.  After you read the last line, `feof(fp)` still returns false, so you go into the loop again and attempt to read another line.  That read fails, but since you don't check the return value of `fscanf`, you don't realize it and instead get a garbage extra value in your array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I don't check for input size is because, as I said, this is an assignment and input size is guaranteed to be consistent. I would have checked for that otherwise, of course.

Thank you for mentioning the return value though, I should indeed make it a habit to actually make use of it whenever possible for error detection. One thing: what would be the difference between while(!feof(fp)) and while(fscanf(...) == 4), here? Since I am reading from a consistent input, not being able to match the items would essentially equate to it being EOF, no? Thank you.